# How to detect sim card change in android

Tags: android, unique-key, sim-card

I have to check if the user is using same sim card, if not i have to logout, like google pay.
Now iam using

```
SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(this);
List<SubscriptionInfo> localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
SubscriptionInfo info = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(0);
info.getIccId()
```

this code to get the iccid
but it is returning empty string in some devices.

is there any solution for this?
can any one suggest an alternate methode to the same result.

Note: Phone state permission are granted

Thank you

Comment: please help me with  this

Comment: Did u find solution for this?

Comment: I didnt get a unique ID, But using SubscriptionId from SubscriptionInfo. it can detect sim changes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a unique ID, But using Subscription Id from SubscriptionInfo.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30825634)